# How to use pensquare with dashed in MetaPost?

Tags: graphics, metapost

<sup>(Sorry, not sure if *MetaPost* topics are off-topic to the site,
please feel free to migrate.)</sup>

I'm trying to draw thick square dashed lines.  Let's say I want to make
a straight cross.  When I use `pencircle`, it works
*okay*, but the edges of the dashes are round:

```metapost
pickup pencircle scaled 0.250 cm;
drawoptions (withcolor black dashed evenly scaled 4);
draw (000, 250) -- (500, 250);
draw (250, 000) -- (250, 500);
```

But when I use `pensquare`, there are no dashes at all, only
a thick solid black line:

```metapost
pickup pensquare scaled 0.250 cm;
drawoptions (withcolor black dashed evenly scaled 4);
draw (000, 250) -- (500, 250);
draw (250, 000) -- (250, 500);
```

Is there a way to get a square dashed line?

Comment: MetaPost is clearly on-topic on this site.  It's just not very popular.  Most people use PGF/TikZ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the bottom of page 40 in the [manual](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf):

> Also, dashed patterns are intended to be used either with pencircle or
>   no pen at all; pensquare and other complex pens should be avoided.
>   This is because the output uses the PostScript primitive setdash,
>   which does not interact well with the filled paths created by
>   polygonal pens.

With that said, I think you can get something close by playing with `linecap:=butt;`
With a circular pen, and no `linecap` options, your dashes look like

[image]

When `linecap:=butt;` is set, your dashes look like the red portion below:

[image]

Maybe this is all you want, I'm not sure.  If you want square "dots", then following along as in the example at the top of page 41, we want to set the dash pattern so that the height and the length of the `linecap:=butt;` dash are equal.  Thus, set the length of the on portion to be the diameter of whatever circular pen you're drawing with, then cap the ends to form a square.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\mplibnumbersystem{double}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
    vardef penwidth=
        save q; pair q;
        % position of q so that when drawn withcurrent pen, the bottom of penstroke=origin.
        bot q=origin;
        % center q is 1/2 radius of pen above origin.
        % double to get diameter of current pen
        pw:=2(ypart q);
        pw
    enddef;
    vardef squaredashes=
        save pica_,picb_; picture pica_,picb_;
        % store picture then clear
        pica_:=currentpicture; currentpicture:=nullpicture;
        % draw your dashpattern
        draw dashpattern(on penwidth off penwidth);
        % store dashpattern, and restore picture
        picb_:=currentpicture; currentpicture:=pica_;
        picb_
    enddef;

 beginfig(0);

    u:=1cm;
    path p; p=origin--(2u,0);
    linecap:=butt;

    pickup pencircle scaled 8bp;
    draw p dashed squaredashes;

    pickup pencircle scaled 3bp;
    draw p shifted (0,-.5u) dashed squaredashes;

endfig;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```